# Ubuntu Studio 23.04 + SSL 2 - guitar input not working

Tags: sound, hardware, external-soundcard

I recently installed the latest Ubuntu Studio 23.04 and it looks like my SSL2 is partially working.
The output works fine, I can hear any playback audio. However when I plug in my guitar it won't capture the input.
Out of curiosity I tested with my old Focusrite 2i4 and everything works fine out of the box.

The patch bay looks fine, Reaper config is fine.

Could you please advise?

Thanks,
Laszlo

Comment: It's reported working on Ubuntu 18.04.5, so it should work on 23.04. Are you using Jack/QjackCtl? If I don't start Jack, I can hear audio through my interface (not an SSL2) but not plugged-in instruments. Only by selecting my interface as the soundcard in Jack and starting it can I hear my guitar. I assume you ARE using Jack because your Focusrite is working. The only other thing I can think of is maybe you have the monitor dial of the SSL2 turned all the way to the right rather than centred or turned to the left? (That's from page 7 of the manual - I don't actually have an SSL2).

Comment: Thanks for the response. It is a brand new Ubuntu install, with out of the box config. All I did is just to install Reaper and a virtual amp on top of that. One more strange thing - when I used the amp in standalone mode and switched to SSL drivers I immediately heard feedback. Maybe I'll try a downgraded Ubuntu.

Comment: If you haven't used it before, use QjackCtl. Plug in your SSL2, then open QjackCtl and go to Setup. In the dropdown under Interface, change the option from (default) to the SSL2 (or whichever is the last name in the list - it's not always the same name as the device). Click Apply, close the window, and press Start. Now you will be using the SSL2 as the sound card rather than your computer's sound card. Then open Reaper. If Reaper doesn't automatically use this new sound card, you might have to find a setting in Reaper to change it. To go back to the computer's sound card, press Stop.

Comment: Once everything is set up and Reaper is open, you can open Connect in the QjackCtl window and, in the Audio tab, see all the possible connections. I haven't used Reaper in a while, but I think one of the connections will be Reaper. The SSL2 will be System (but only after you have selected it as Interface as I mentioned above). If there is no connection between System on the left and Reaper on the right, connect them and hopefully you should have some luck. I'm surprised the SSL2 is working differently for you than the Focusrite. I haven't used either, but both my interfaces work the same way.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have tried them, the connections in QJackCtl are connecting to the correct places (SSL left to Reaper Left, SSL right to Reaper right). Even I restarted Jack services. 
Ubuntu 23.04 has a new default patch app called Patchance, the connections are identical to the QJackCtl ones. 
Reaper is using JACK as a default Audio system.
Unfortunately I have the same issue. The sound card picks up the signal, but Linux won't.

Comment: Dang, sorry I can't be more help. I'm not sure if promoting another website is allowed here (it's not my own website), but if you haven't already, check out the forum linuxmusicians.com. Lots of knowledgeable people there. There is also forum.cockos.com, which is for Reaper in general (not specific to Linux, but I have seen Linux-related info there). Good luck!